# C# Queue batchs and applications in the same process

Tags: c#, batch-file, process

I need to achieve the following : call some 3rd party bat/cmd file I dont know nothing about in a process and then start another application in the very same process (some env variables might have been set). I also need to compute some stuff after the batch has been executed.

So far, using process RedirectStandardInput, I am able to queue several commands in the same process :

```
[...]
cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
cmdProcess.Start();

using (var sw = cmdProcess.StandardInput)
{
    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(FirstBatFile);
        SomeAction();
        sw.WriteLine(SecondApplication);
    }
}
```

My problem is : I have to make sure the first bat command is done before doing anything in my SomeAction() method and before calling the final application. And I really dont know how to achieve that. Everything is executed when the StandardInput closes, so I have to find a proper way to monitor the end of the batch command.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: [.WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Well, I can use WaitForExit to wait for the end of the batch process, read the env variables set if any, and start a new process with the final targeted application with the new variables set. I did hope something more elegant would exist :(

Comment: If you know something about the output you can hook into `process.OutputDataReceived` and test the data you get there until its the expected final piece of data..

Comment: Unhopefully, I dont. However that could be one alternative if 3rd parties accept that.

Comment: I was going to add: If you don't you should be able to wrap the calls in a batch file, which will output what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run all batch files and programs in same console context to retain environmental values set by batch scripts.

One possible way to do it is yet another batch file.

For example:

a.bat:

```
set myVariable=c:\file.txt
```

b.bat:

```
echo %myVariable%
```

c.bat:

```
call a.bat
call b.bat
notepad.exe %myVariable%
```

It will run batch files and program in same context, thus retaining envvars.

Alternatively you could force it into command line to cmd. However if file path in envvar will be surrounded by quote characters  it will merge it with current working directory.

```
cmd /c "call a.bat & call b.bat & notepad.exe %myVariable%"
```

Comment: Well, it seems to be the best way to queue n scripts. Thanks for your quick answers.